# intuition for mixing problems with ODEs

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling

assume we have a mixing problem with a salt solution coming into a water tank. the flow rate in and flow out rate are equal (5 L/hour), the concentration of salt flowing in is 1 g/L and the tank contains 100 L of water. this is described by the ODE,

$\displaystyle\frac{dS}{dt} = 5\times 1 - 5\displaystyle\frac{S}{100}$

if the tank contains no salt initially it takes ~1 hour to add 5 g of salt to it. however, if tank starts with 5 g of salt and pure water is flowed into the tank then after 1 hour there will be ~4.7 grams of salt in tank, not roughly 0 grams. this asymmetry is counterintuitive - is there a physical explanation for it?

if we instead had 95 grams of salt in the tank to start with and flowed in pure water at the rates described above, then after 1 hour there would be 90 grams of salt in the tank, as expected (since going from 0 grams to 5 grams took 1 hour when we flowed salt in.) put another way, the solution equation $S(t)$ to the ODE is not linear. what is the intuition behind the initial amount of salt making such a big difference to the rate, physically?

Comment: Sorry, but I'm slightly suspicious about the behaviour of solutions that you've told us. They just don't fit into the equation you've written.

Comment: it's possible that my solution is wrong will double check again

Comment: @Evgeny: I checked the solution with equation solver. the rate at which you remove 5 grams of salt from tank is different if you start with 95 grams versus if you start with 5 grams. also flowing 5 grams starting from 0 takes less time than clearing out 5 grams if you start with 5 grams. this is the counterintuitive part that i don't understand

Comment: It's not everywhere clear what do you mean exactly. I think that your intuition leads you in wrong direction because you think that rate at which this process goes should be the same for all times and all amounts of salt in tank. But it's not.

Comment: @Evgeny: I realize my intuition is wrong and my question is why. Why should pumping out salt be different than pumping in salt, physically?

Comment: The rate of salt going out changes with time because the concentration of salt is always changing, and the out rate is proportional to the concentration, as your equation describes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no asymmetry other than you can add salt much more quickly than
you can remove it.

Keep in mind, the time constant here is 20 hours, so not much happens in
an hour, so for periods of an hour, the rate of change of salt is
well approximated by $-{1 \over 20} S + u$, where $u=5$ when you add salt
but $u=0$ when adding pure water, and $S$ is the initial amount of salt.

If you add 5 l in an hour at a concentration of 1 g/l, then you add 
$\approx -{1 \over 20} 0 + 5$ g in an hour.

The tank loses 5 l in an hour, so if you start with 5 g in  100 l, you would expect to add (well, lose) $\approx -{1 \over 20} 5 + 0$ g in an hour.

In the second case we have an initial 95 g and add pure water, so
you would expect to add (well, lose) $\approx
-{1 \over 20} 95 + 0$ g in an hour.

The system is linear as a map from the initial state $S(0)$ and the 
rate of salt addition $t \mapsto u(t)$ to the function $t \mapsto S(t)$.

Comment: to clarify, that you can "add salt much more quickly than you can remove it" is the asymmetry i was referring to. not sure what you mean by "the time constant here is 20 hours"

Comment: The governing differential equation is $\dot{S} = -{1 \over 20} S +u$, and the unforced solution is of the form $S(0)e^{-{1 \over 20} t}$, the $20$ is referred to as the time constant (time taken for the initial value to drop to $e^{-1}$ of the initial value).